# Invocation target exception in web-services using glassfish 4.0

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I am facing an issue when running web-services locally using the tester page provided by netbeans IDE 7.4.
I am able to deploy the war successfully and then i go for the "Test web-service" option in the web services folder of the project. This opens a tester page where all the operations are listed with text fields for input parameters and button to run the operation.
However, i get an exception when running the operation. Also, i do not see any logs in the server console(IDE). The only logs i see are in the browser which are given below. I  have tried using Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox browsers.

WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message : null; Refer to the server log for more details
Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:336) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:106) at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:136) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:242) at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:193) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114) at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:307) ... 23 more Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:323) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:272) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:230) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:143) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154) at $Proxy427.activateAccount(Unknown Source) ... 28 more

Comment: The log shows that it is an authorization problem. You do not provide enough information to know where exactly the issue is.